# Texture not applied, just the color

Tags: texturing, particles, image, color

Pretty much the title.

[image]

As you can see on the image, grass and leafs texture is working, applied and looking not that bad. 
However, the bark texture I applied to the tree is showed just as a close color. I'm pretty new in Blender, so please could you throw some advices? 
Also when I go to UV Editor screen, there is no texture.

Tell me what further info you need and I will provide!

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Probably it doesn't have a UVMap.

Comment: please share blender file (you can remove all objects that are ok) - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/U5Z7EcH

Answer (score 0):

If you have a texture image than you probably forgot to Choose it for your UV.Go to UV than select new file (locate that image) Now turn the edit mode and go back to UV tab and make the highlighted cubes fit the whole image.
If you already have an image selected than it must be because you haven't done the shading part correctly.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/U5Z7EcH